# MySql client for Linux

Tags: linux, mysql

What MySql client are you using for Linux. I currently use PhpMyAdmin and the Mysql Query Browser but I would like something similar to Toad or HeidiSql that I use on windows. One with SQL code completion.

Comment: is code completion the only additional requirement you're looking for?

Comment: The more I can get, the better. Basically looking for the best MySql client on linux. I'm a developer, so writing losts of SQL scripts and my databases are getting big. Writing Stored Procedures often also, so anything that will make my life easier. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [SqlYog](http://www.webyog.com/) running under Wine.  This is because quite simply no linux tools that I've found come close to matching the raw power and flexability of SqlYog.  This is one of the few non open-source software tools that I use for open source development.
[image: Below screenshot shows SQLyog running under Gnome evnironment]

Comment: Really looks like a good one. I see Google is also using it. Pity they don't have a native one for Linux, but Wine should do I suppose.

Comment: Oh I fonrgot to mention that the code completion in SqlYog will also complete the object (tables,columns) names within your database.

Answer (score 5):

[Tora](http://torasql.com/) (Qt client) and [Mysql-Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (official MySQL client, in GTK) are another alternatives for Linux.

Comment: +1 for mySQL-Workbench. Even Oracle SQL developer works with 3rd party add-on, this official program works perfectly under linux (RHEL 6 in my case).

Answer (score 4):

I have always prefered [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) . Its a universal sql client - so you can use the app to connect to mysql , msSql , Oracle , etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this list](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/toad-for-oracle/?platform=linux&sort=likes) for Toad from [http://alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/)
<strike>I'm pretty sure [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) will do what you want on linux.</strike>

Comment: I'm pretty sure Oracle SQL Developer won't work with MySQL

Comment: heheh. I totally missed that.

Comment: In fact there is a third party driver which can be instelled through the SQL Developer Update menu which supports mySQL. I did used it and it was also working

Answer (score 1):

You might find [crunchyfrog](http://code.google.com/p/crunchyfrog/) useful, should you ever have to work with databases other than MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I like runsqlrun -> https://bitbucket.org/andialbrecht/runsqlrun/

This is fork the CrunchyFrog with python3 and gtk3.